# Angular custom form input with error message

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I'd like to create a custom form input that is just a wrapper around the normal input and that displays an error message in case the `formControl` isn't valid.

So I made a component implementing `ControlValueAccessor` but now that I want to display the error message I realize I have no hold of the `FormControl`, thus I need to pass it as `@Input()`. The problem is... Why implement the ControlValueAccessor in the first place if I can just pass the `FormControl` as input ? I'm confused.

**html**

```
<input  
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [type]="type" 
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  (keyup)="onChange()"
  (change)="onChange()" 
  (blur)="onTouched()" 
  [disabled]="disabled"/>
```

**ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-app',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() type = 'text';
  @Input() placeholder = 'placeholder';
  @Input() errorMsg = '';
  value: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  private onChangeFn;
  private onTouchedFn;

  writeValue(val: string | number): void {
    this.value = val;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeFn = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedFn = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  onChange(){
    this.onChangeFn(this.value);
  }

  onTouched(){
    this.onTouchedFn();
  }

}
```